# Sending SSL client certificate from Apache via a company proxy to a thirdparty system

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy, openssl

I am trying to setup the following:

User ---https---> Apache ---http---> Company Proxy ---https---> Third party webserver (nginx)

The Apache must send an SSL client certificate for authentication by the webserver. 
I am using Apache 2.4.41 / OpenSSL 1.1.1d.

If I am testing the setup with curl and sending the SSL client cert to the webserver via the company
(i.e. bypassing the Apache), it works perfectly. However, if I am using curl to connect to the Apache,
it fails.

I have configured (relevant parts only) as an Apache VHost

===

```
ServerName test1.company.com:5140

SSLEngine on
KeepAlive on

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

SSLProxyCACertificateFile conf/ssl/ca-bundle-proxy.crt

# client certificate (contains unencrypted concatenated private key and server certificate)
SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile ssl.client

ProxyRemote "*" "http://proxy.company.de:8080"

ProxyTimeout 30
Timeout 30

# explicity required
ProxyPreserveHost Off

<Location /mycontext>
    ProxyPass                    https://www.thirdparty.com:443/mycontext
    ProxyPassReverse             https://www.thirdparty.com:443/mycontext
</Location>
```

I get in the logfile (extract):

```
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.150538 2020] [ssl:trace4] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_io.c(2212): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#7fc57000ddb0 [mem: 7fc57002f863] (BIO dump follows)
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.150558 2020] [ssl:trace4] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_io.c(2212): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: read 117/204 bytes from BIO#7fc57000ddb0 [mem: 7fc57002f868] (BIO dump follows)
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.165597 2020] [ssl:trace4] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_io.c(2212): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: read 87/87 bytes from BIO#7fc57000ddb0 [mem: 7fc57002f8dd] (BIO dump follows)
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.165643 2020] [ssl:trace3] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2192): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read server key exchange
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.165687 2020] [ssl:debug]  [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1943): AH02267: Proxy client certificate callback: (test1.company.com:5140) entered
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.165691 2020] [ssl:debug]  [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2013): AH02269: Proxy client certificate callback: (test1.company.com:5140) no client certificate found!?
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.165708 2020] [ssl:trace3] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2192): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read server certificate request
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.165712 2020] [ssl:trace3] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2192): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read server done
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.165722 2020] [ssl:trace3] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2192): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write client certificate
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.165881 2020] [ssl:trace3] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2192): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write client key exchange
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.165910 2020] [ssl:trace3] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2192): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.165947 2020] [ssl:trace4] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_io.c(2212): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: write 138/138 bytes to BIO#7fc57000e190 [mem: 7fc57002a5a0] (BIO dump follows)
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.235214 2020] [ssl:trace3] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2192): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read change cipher spec
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.235242 2020] [ssl:trace3] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2192): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read finished
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.235254 2020] [ssl:trace3] [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2187): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] OpenSSL: Handshake: done
[Mon Mar 23 14:18:26.235265 2020] [ssl:debug]  [pid 116307:tid 140486627026688] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2236): [remote proxy.company.com:8080] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
```

The output of curl via the Apache :

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 13:18:26 GMT
< Server: nginx
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 246
< Connection: close
<
<html>
<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head>
```

Questions:

1. Why does it say "no client certificate found!?" and "write client certificate" ? It's a little bit confusing.
2. As far as I know, the exchange of the SSL client certificate is done in the SSL handshake. How can the handshake be completed if there is an error with sending the client cert?
3. Does anybody have an idea what needs to be changed in the Apache configuration to get this working?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Christian

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do. But, in your current setup Apache is terminating the SSL connection. This means only Apache will see the client certificate. It cannot forward the client certificate to the next system since it does not have access to the private key of the client certificate (only the client does). For client certificates you need end-to-end-TLS and not end-to-proxy TLS followed by proxy-to-end TLS.

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for your answer. I am not trying to forward the client certificate. I want to authenticate with the SSL client certificate from the Apache towards the third party system.

Comment: You are trying to make Apache use a certificate of a client to authenticate against a different server, i.e. client-apache-TLS with the clients certificate followed by apache-server-TLS with the client certificate. The latter is not possible since Apache does not have the private key to the certificate. Client certificates requires end-to-end-TLS, i.e. client-server-TLS not client-proxy-TLS followed by proxy-server-TLS.

Comment: let me try to explain it better:

The setup is:
User ---https---> Apache ---http---> Company Proxy ---https---> Third party webserver (nginx)

The Apache terminates the SSL connection from the user. The user does not send a client certificate.

The Apache should open a new connection to the third party system, by using its own SSL client certificate
defined with "SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile ssl.client". 
The file ssl.client contains the unencrypted concatenated private key and certificate.

I hope, this solves now the misunderstanding - and I hope this is possible :)

Comment: Thanks, now its clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does it say "no client certificate found!?" and "write client certificate" ? It's a little bit confusing.

If the server requested a client certificate the client will send the requested Certificate record. But this might contain nothing (i.e. 0 certificates).

> As far as I know, the exchange of the SSL client certificate is done in the SSL handshake. How can the handshake be completed if there is an error with sending the client cert?

A client certificate can be mandatory or optional. The client cannot see if it is mandatory or not, only that a certificate is requested. The server or application might decide to check if the certificate is the expected one after the handshake itself is completed. Only if the handshake is completed the client can send a HTTP request and get a HTTP response with the comparably nice error message. Otherwise the client would just get a strange handshake error.

> Does anybody have an idea what needs to be changed in the Apache configuration to get this working?

The config you present looks actually good but the problem might be in the details. For example the certificate file might be wrong so that a certificate and key cannot actually be found inside. Hard to tell without having a look at these kind of details. Or the certificate does not match the list of CA the server presented as possible issuers for the client certificate.